# How to set stacksize to unlimited OS X 10.8?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, stack-size

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but when I type

`$limit stacksize unlimited`

Into a terminal on Mountain Lion I get:

`-bash: limit: command not found`

and so I try:

`sudo ulimit -s unlimited`

Which won't work either. Can you please tell me what I should be using to get an unlimited stacksize in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now realised that for the limit command I need to use a tcsh shell.